# Robot Framework -UnknownAllure Report

Tags: robotframework, allure

**Robot Framework:** 3.1.2
**allure-robotframework**==2.8.16

I am getting the following information in generated allure report.

**Cmd Line:-**

```
Directory path>allure serve 'Path where output.xml exists'
Generating report to temp directory...
Report successfully generated to Temp\allure-report
Starting web server...
2020-06-07 11:39:56.235:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1608ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Server started at <foo>. Press <Ctrl+C> to exit
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

[image]

Could someone help me as to what changes to be made to get proper data populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pip install allure-robotframework
$ robot --listener allure_robotframework ./my_robot_test
```

https://pypi.org/project/allure-robotframework/